# Load cell for Capsule filling machine

Tags: load-cell

(I am new in this era, so go easy on me :) )

I am working on a project that involves weight filling of powdered material into capsules (Fill sizes, 400 , 600 & 800 mg). . Now for the design of weight part of the machine, we need to employ load sensors with a resolution of 1mg. I have tried locating sensors according to my needs and couldn't locate it. The sensors are either very high resolution (0.1 mg and downwards) or too low resolution (1 g and onwards). The problem is that the sensors with high resolutions (0.1 mg and lower) are extremely expensive. I also dug out the idea that the already existing weighing machines with resolution of 1 mg are available in the market and can be hacked into doing my job (and they are cheap, around 10 $). Does sensors with such resolution exist in the same price range (so we dont have to deal with the weighing machine circuitry) ?

Now as this is a totally new field for me, any guidance towards the right direction would be useful. I am not particularly looking for recommendations, but if anyone has a good experience working with such parts, it would be very helpful.

Comment: This is perhaps not what you want... but we just bought one of these.. it does 1 mg.  http://www.amazon.com/Nevada-Weighing-Tree-Precision-Balance/dp/B00BRYG5WA

Comment: Your instrument should measure with at least one order of magnitude more precision than your measurements have to be...

Answer (score 1):

Digital scales with range 10g and claimed resolution 1mg are available for [low cost](http://www.dx.com/p/digital-jewellery-scale-10g-2060#.VJHYvcnLJ1M). There's no reason why you couldn't remove the load cells and substitute your own circuitry. The resolution is not necessarily an indication of how accurate they will be. You can make the circuitry show resolution of 1ppm, but thermal stability and hysteresis will mean you can't get useful accuracy at anywhere near that level.

I suggest you try to match the maximum full scale measurement to the load cell as the first step. If you only need to go to 1gram full scale then don't try to use a 500g load cell.

Comment: Thanks, The full scale measurement I am aiming at is around 10 - 20 gms (considering the weighing platform weight). I found out one load cell which apparently meets my specs, but temp effect on zero looks a little high to me.
http://www.manyyear.com/Weighing/Parallel_Beam_Load_Cell/MLC608M%20micro%20force%20force%20test.html

Comment: You may have to use a better load cell (expensive) and/or temperature compensate it (also expensive, but can be done in-house for you).

Comment: Thanks, any guidance, links or tutorials about that ? which you would recommend me to have a look .. that would be great ..

Comment: @Muzammil Look at all the load cell circuits and application notes, especially from Analog Devices, LTC and TI née Burr Brown (analog heavy hitters).

Comment: perfect, I will. I got to see these load sensors, Apparently they look good. (my feed size is 400 mg, and I can accept an error of 5 - 10 mg)
http://bingfst.en.alibaba.com/product/1923649066-221818974/0_001g_high_precision_aluminium_alloy_Weight_Measuring_Sensor_load_cell.html